# How to refresh the token and cookies using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-scraping, webforms, urlfetch

I want to auto-refresh the `verification token` and `Cookie` each time I make a request using Google Apps Script? I post Pin on this [web form](https://taxdelinquent.cookcountyclerkil.gov/) and extract the results back to Google sheet, I used the following snippet:

```
 function submitForm() {
  var url = "https://taxdelinquent.cookcountyclerkil.gov/";
  var formData = {
     '__RequestVerificationToken': 'q5mCwHyTYkN3HgYB3NZXS-JvsGLfvH5bmRtpJKPWTmml_Oskif_gIW3vnU8jNbhZC_XW2xlmCyGqHAhISUjtX-zbZdoIQBiOulF44suHU1c1',
    'Pin': '13-30-300-016-0000'
  };

  var encodedData = Object.keys(formData).map(function(key) {
    return encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(formData[key]);
  }).join('&');

  var headers = {
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml",
    "Cookie": "__RequestVerificationToken=wOpZrdbvOL7wiQJcqlWYSAlsLIBc5yImjoHSGqSixBZewlt2FZgNLQXh9xH5APz2_bCkcgxPmckSipc1sRExCbLEOYcmCRrWTqNhX8mVtqk1; AWSALB=KsF6dcBJ9rQjYyLrj1veloVO595F9XgoQyhW2wcXz8AC6XuxVBcklT3NdYfQ8p32s2w/pzyVw5w7QcJ7NBnAhb3LcpBoWAyN6hwsXjzXMvr4fZhbEZ4KAMXHjbU8; AWSALBCORS=KsF6dcBJ9rQjYyLrj1veloVO595F9XgoQyhW2wcXz8AC6XuxVBcklT3NdYfQ8p32s2w/pzyVw5w7QcJ7NBnAhb3LcpBoWAyN6hwsXjzXMvr4fZhbEZ4KAMXHjbU8"
  };

  var options = {
    "method": "post",  // or "get" depending on your needs
    "headers": headers,
    "payload": encodedData
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options).getContentText();
}
```

It produces the required data. If you go to `inspect element` of this [website](https://taxdelinquent.cookcountyclerkil.gov/), you will see the payload like this:

[image: Form Elements].

The **data to be extracted** looks like this:

[image: Data to be parsed]

However I believe that when this **verification token** and **Cookie** expire, script would not be able to get the data, I need your guidance to resolve this. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Try to make a plain request.. that token should be somewhere in the response html. Take it and make the authenticated request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, using the following script I am able to get `verification token` and `cookies` and use it in above script `submitForm()`:

```
function getTokenCookie(url) {

  var options = {
    "method": "get", 
  };

  // Make the HTTP request
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  var cookies = response.getAllHeaders()["Set-Cookie"];

  var htmlContent = response.getContentText();
  var match = htmlContent.match(/<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="([^"]+)" \/>/);

  if (match && match.length > 1) {
    var verificationToken = match[1];
    return [verificationToken,cookies];
  } else {
    Logger.log("Unable to find __RequestVerificationToken in the HTML content.");
  }
}
```

This script gets both the values **(token,cookies)** from the webpage to be used for data scraping.